# Ms Access Query not working for Insert Statement

Tags: java, ms-access

I am Executing Query

```
insert into paymentdetails(fov,fse,nform,total) values(120,120,200,1640) where docketno='60000000';
```

After executing it in Ms Access i am Getting an Error

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.
```

can any one tell what is the issue.?

Comment: there are Six Field in database out of Which two columns already have values and i want insert values for next Four Columns.

Comment: Is there any Solution without using update Query.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to update values if that row is exists.

To insert a row

```
str="INSERT INTO TableName (Col1,Col2) VALUES (va1,va2)";
```

To update an existing row,

```
str="UPDATE TableName Set Col1=Val1, Col2=Val2 WHERE Col3=Val3";
```

Comment: using update its possible. But i want to know whether  its possible in another way.?

Comment: Take a look at [MS-ACCESS SQL Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208861(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

How can you have a WHERE clause in an INSERT statement? Don't you mean UPDATE?

or

Just remove the WHERE clause to insert a new record.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove 'where' condition, Execute like :

```
insert into paymentdetails(fov,fse,nform,total) values(120,120,200,1640);
```

if , you want to execute with where then use select statment like :

```
insert into paymentdetails(fov,fse,nform,total) 

select col1,col2,col3,col4 from tablename  where docketno='60000000';
```